# Run exe file with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, exe

I want to know if there is a way to open a exe file from client side with jQuery or JavaScript.

I tried with `windows.open("..")` but it didn't work.

Comment: no you can't. For security reasons

Comment: Why do you want to run an executable on the machine of someone using your webpage?

Comment: Generally speaking you can only run an exe with a server side language, with that being said, there is nothing stopping you from calling a server side script using a client side language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, Dalorzo is correct - you cannot escape the sandbox of a browser without earning lots of money.  Recently Pinky Pie won over $60k from Google for performing such a task on Google Chrome.

http://blog.chromium.org/2012/05/tale-of-two-pwnies-part-1.html

However, sometimes I ask questions to try to find out-of-the-box solutions, so I'm assuming that you have a legitimate use-case for this question.  I can help you think of a "hack" solution if you have a legitimate use for this.  I'll probably get downvoted to oblivion for this response, but theoretically you *could* do this...

Back in college, I took a computer forensics class in which I wrote a chat web application which would forensically clean a user's computer from having ever accessed the chat webpage.  This was done through the user running an executable they could download from the site.  However, I wanted to have the users to not have to run the executable every time so I wanted a sandbox escape like you're asking about.

It's messy, but if your users are a participating party they can modify their computer to allow executables to be run from Chrome webpages.

**Please Note:**  This will make your computer less secure, I only ever did it on Virtual Machines or Lab Machines.  Reconsider whether you *actually* wanna try this or not.

**Step One:**  *Create a Chrome custom browser:*

This is the python that I eventually compiled to a packed *.exe that accomplished creating a Google Chrome custom browser.

```
import sqlite3 as lite
con = lite.connect('C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data')
c = con.cursor()
#idmax = c.execute('SELECT MAX(id) FROM keywords')
#c.execute("INSERT INTO keywords  VALUES('cleanupeverybodyeverywhere','cleanupeverybodyeverywhere','','forensichat://C:>Windows>System32>calc.exe',0,'',0,0,'',0,'',0,0,'',0,'','','','','','','','','')")
c.execute("SELECT * FROM keywords WHERE short_name='cleanupeverybodyeverywhere'")
foo = c.fetchall()
if foo == []:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO keywords (short_name,keyword,url,favicon_url) VALUES ('cleanupeverybodyeverywhere','cleanupeverybodyeverywhere','forensichat://C:>Windows>System32>calc.exe','')")
    con.commit()
con.close()
```

Note that now when I open a Chrome tab and use the custom browser `cleanupeverybodyeverywhere` to run the key `forensichat` and it will open `calc.exe` as proof of concept.

**Step Two:**  *Modify your Windows Registry:*

```
import _winreg as wreg
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
key = wreg.CreateKey(wreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, '')
wreg.SetValue(key,'forensichat',wreg.REG_SZ,'URL:forensichat Protocol')
# Create new subkey
kkey = wreg.CreateKey(wreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, 'forensichat')
wreg.SetValueEx(kkey, 'URL Protocol', 0, wreg.REG_SZ,'')

# Create new value
wreg.CreateKey(wreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,"forensichat\shell")
nkey = wreg.CreateKey(wreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,"forensichat\shell\open")
wreg.SetValue(nkey,"command",wreg.REG_SZ,'C:\Users\\'+user+'\Downloads\\forensicleaner.exe')

key.Close()
```

Note that I'm creating a key called `forensichat` which will run the `exe` found in the user's Downloads folder.

Of course, I ended up cleaning this all up and packing it so Anti-Virus wouldn't flag it, next thing I know Google Chrome has marked the site lol.  It's still up if you [wanna check it out](http://chat.adamschaal.com) - check `Secure Chat` and `Repeat Customer`.  Chrome will flag it, but there's obviously ways around that.